# Error executing DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE in Oracle

Tags: oracle, dbms-output

I am running `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` to send a message from a procedure and I am trying to display the debug information of what a type variable contains `BFILE`

```
create or replace PROCEDURE P_FILEUPLOAD_XML IS

v_dir       gzvcatg.gzvcatg_desc11%TYPE;
l_dir       VARCHAR2(35);
l_fil       VARCHAR2(30) := 'ES0000251446027471.xml'; 
l_loc       BFILE;

BEGIN

        l_loc := BFILENAME(v_dir,l_fil);

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_loc); 

END;
```

At the moment of executing my procedure and waiting for a response from the log:

[image]

Anyone know why the error is due and how to correct it.

**UPDATE:**

Following the recommendation in the MT0 response making use of `DBMS_LOB.READ`, try the following:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE P_FILEUPLOAD_XML IS

    v_dir       gzvcatg.gzvcatg_desc11%TYPE;
    l_dir       VARCHAR2(35);
    l_fil       VARCHAR2(30) := 'ES0000251446027471.xml'; 
    l_loc       BFILE;

    BEGIN

            l_loc := BFILENAME(v_dir,l_fil);

            DBMS_LOB.READ(l_loc IN BFILE); 

    END;
```

But executing it generates the following error:

[image]

Comment: You can't "print" a BFILE.  what are you trying to do?  Unclear. You want to read the file and print it out?  Read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/adlob/LOB-APIs-for-BFILE-operations.html#GUID-43A8979C-97AC-4F97-9B5C-F44E72FE64F4)

Comment: Print on console what the variable contains `l_loc`

Comment: YOu need to use the [LOB API function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_lob.htm#ARPLS66624)

Comment: The variable `l_loc` is of data type `bfile`. That data type can't be converted to a string, to be printed with `put_line`. `bfile` is an object data type, made up of a file name and an internal alias for that file's location. So - what were you trying to print?

Comment: @mathguy How would it be the correct way to show what the `l_loc` variable contains in the log

Comment: what log are you talking about??

Comment: @OldProgrammer Sorry, I mean showing what the `l_loc` variable in console contains

Comment: @MT0 answered your question on how to read the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Anyone know why the error is due

`l_loc` is a `BFILE`.

[`DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( item IN VARCHAR2 )`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_output.htm#ARPLS67327) takes a `VARCHAR2` data type as its argument.

You cannot implicitly cast a `BFILE` to a `VARCHAR2` so the procedure call raise an exception as it is the wrong type of argument to call the function with.

> and how to correct it.

Read the file using [`DBMS_LOB.READ`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_lob.htm#ARPLS66738) and use `UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2` to convert the `RAW` value you get from the LOB to a string so you can print it.

Comment: Some example of how to print in the log what the `BFILE` variable contains

Comment: You can be more detailed with the function `DBMS_LOB.READ`, I don't know her and I don't understand the documentation.

Comment: Check my question again, I am using `DBMS_LOB.READ` but it generates an error